# DataWeave best practices when null variable assignment

Tags: json, mule, integration, transformation, dataweave

This is a JSON-JSON transformation, transforming a boolean input `("true"|"false")` into a char output `('Y'|'N')`.
So we go for something like:

```
varOutput: ('Y' when payload.varInput otherwise 'N')
```

But what if varInput is null? we got exception. I could control it with another when-otherwise:

```
varOutput: ('Y' when payload.varInput != null otherwise 'N')
when payload.varInput != null otherwise null,
```

This last one is null safe, but again, I feel there should be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `default`

```
{varOutput: ( payload.varInput default 'N')
 }
```

Or unless/otherwise is null safe and a bit more elegant:

```
{ 
    varOutput: ('Y' unless payload.varInput !=null otherwise 'N')
}
```

Comment: Still need to convert the true to 'Y'.  How about { varOutput: 'Y' when (payload.varInput default false) default 'N' }

Comment: Sure, looks good. added another option of unless/otherwise too.